# Different Images on Single view for Multiple buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uibutton

In my `UIView` am having 4 `buttons` Like `animals`,`birds`,``` nature``fruits ```. While clicking the other view shows the set of selected category `images`. Instead of putting 4 `views` for 4 buttons i want to perform in single view?Can any one tell idea regarding this??

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you take one `imageView` and on each button click just call `imageView.setBackgroudResource(Your_image_from_drawable);` in this way you dont need to use four imageView.